# react with alt and webpack: unexpected token at @datasource

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, alt

I am trying to create a Todos example app using the generator-react-webpack from [here](https://github.com/newtriks/generator-react-webpack). Everything works until I started using alt for the flux pattern. When I run the project using `npm run`, I got the following error:

```
TodoStore.js: Unexpected token (12:0)
  10 | import _ from 'lodash';
  11 | 
  12 | @datasource(CategorySource)
```

It complains about the line 12 above for the @datasource decorator. Below is the code from my TodoStore.js:

```
'use strict';

const alt = require('../alt');
const Actions = require('../actions');
import {decorate, bind, datasource} from 'alt/utils/decorators';
import CategorySource from '../sources/CategorySource';
import _ from 'lodash';

@datasource(CategorySource)
@decorate(alt)
class TodoStore {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            user: null,
            todos: null,
            todosLoading: true
        };
    }

    @bind(Actions.todosLoading)
    todosLoading() {
        this.setState({
            todosLoading: true
        });
    }

    @bind(Actions.todosReceived)
    receivedTodos(todos) {
        _(todos)
        .keys()
        .each((k) => {
            todos[k].key = k;
        })
        .value();

        this.setState({todos, todosLoading: false});
    }

    @bind(Actions.categoriesReceived)
    receivedCategories(categories) {
        let selectedCategory;
        _(categories)
        .keys()
        .each((key, index) => {
            categories[key].key = key;
            if (index == 0) {
                categories[key].selected = true;
                selectedCategory = categories[key];
            }
        })
        .value();

        this.setState({categories, selectedCategory, todosDirty: true});
    }

    @bind(Actions.login)
    login(user) {
        this.setState({user: user});
    }
}

export default alt.createStore(TodoStore);
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374451/webpack-with-react-modules-giving-unexpected-token) for a similar problem, but I don't have any luck getting it to work by changing this line: `test: /\.jsx?$/`, in my webpack.config.js file.

Answer (score 0):

found out the reason: because it does not recognize the ES7 decorator syntax. I created a file named `.babelrc` at the root and its content is:

```
{
  "stage": 0
}
```

Now everything works! Hope this will help someone in the future.